# Is there luggage storage at Canberra Jolimont?

Tags: luggage-storage, canberra

I'll be in Canberra on Saturday for about half a day. The place I usually stay isn't available, so I'm hoping to leave my bags at the Jolimont bus station and do some shopping.

I'm wondering if there are such facilities - that is - luggage storage, at Canberra Jolimont station? I'll be arriving on Murrays and leaving on Greyhound, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

According to another person who had the same problem like you, yes there is a luggage storage.

> Good news is that locker room is available in Canberra and it is affordable and practical. It is located right behind the Murrays counter in Jolimont Centre where coaches stop.

[source](http://www.enidhi.net/2016/02/lockers-cloakroom-luggage-storage-at-canberra-bus-terminal.html)

The source also provides pictures of the lockers and prices according to Feb. 2016 (at least an indicator).

Answer (score 2):

Alas, Murrays no longer has luggage storage, I was directed to **Greyhound** (same terminal).

For $10 a small bag, or $15 for a large, they'll store it - but only up to just before 6pm when their counter closes.  It's in a locked room and is very secure.